# How can I create an overlapping bar graph? Not a stacked bar graph, but a bar graph where the seprate sections overlap on top of each other

Tags: python, plotly

Here is my function for creating my graph:

```
// Function to generate environmental overlapping bar chart
function generateEnvironmentalGraph(electricVehicle, gasVehicle) {
    var categories = [
        "Production du carburant (tCO2e)",
        "Fabrication du vehicule (tCO2e)",
        "Fabrication de batterie (tCO2e)",
        "Emissions d'echappement (tCO2e)"
    ];

    var electricValues = categories.map(function (category) {
        return electricVehicle
            ? electricEnvironmentData[electricVehicle][category]
            : 0;
    });

    var gasValues = categories.map(function (category) {
        return gasVehicle
            ? gasEnvironmentData[gasVehicle][category]
            : 0;
    });

    var electricEnvironmentGraphData = {
        x: categories,
        y: electricValues,
        type: 'bar',
        name: 'Electric',
        marker: {
            color: 'rgba(55,128,191,0.7)',
            line: {
                color: 'rgba(55,128,191,1.0)',
                width: 2
            }
        }
    };

    var gasEnvironmentGraphData = {
        x: categories,
        y: gasValues,
        type: 'bar',
        name: 'Gas',
        marker: {
            color: 'rgba(219, 64, 82, 0.7)',
            line: {
                color: 'rgba(219, 64, 82, 1.0)',
                width: 2
            }
        }
    };

    var layout = {
        title: 'Environmental Impact Comparison',
        xaxis: {
            title: 'Category'
        },
        yaxis: {
            title: 'tCO2e'
        },
        barmode: 'overlay'  
    };

    Plotly.newPlot('electricEnvironmentGraph', [electricEnvironmentGraphData], layout);
    Plotly.newPlot('gasEnvironmentGraph', [gasEnvironmentGraphData], layout);
}
```

Instead of generating an overlaying bar graph, where there is one bar per graph with the tallest section being the Total and the other smaller sections overlaying on top of it, it creates a graph with 5 different sections and it is simply the numbers displayed.

[Graph display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSBXM.png)

I was expecting that it would display an overlaying bar graph, with one bar per graph, with the sections overlapping each other in the order of the categories in the code..